# How to determine if a type has TypeConverterAttribute

Tags: c#, types, attributes

I have a type and I wish to determine at run time if it has the following attribute:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
```

I've tried to use:

```
Attribute.IsDefined(Type attributeType, bool inherit)
```

but I'm having problems specifying the first parameter of this method.

If the attribute was just `[TypeConverter]` it would seemingly be straightforward, but using

```
typeof(TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))
```

gives a compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
```

This line creates an object of `TypeConverterAttribute` with `ExpandableObjectConverter` as a parameter ([TypeConverterAttribute Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ydke9w9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and binds it to your type.

At first you get the defined attribute. In your case it is `TypeConverterAttribute`.
After that you check attribute parameter `ConverterTypeName`.

```
TypeConverterAttribute myAttribute = (TypeConverterAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType(), typeof (TypeConverterAttribute));
if(myAttribute != null)
{
   String typeName = myAttribute.ConverterTypeName;
   Type t = Type.GetType(typeName);
   if(t == typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))
   {
       //..
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case I also had to check the interfaces of my type and the base class for completeness.